# Cant separate from the flex box

Tags: html, css

Trying to separate the logo flex box from the social flex box to put fb tt Instagram logos, but it won't work.

Also, I'm trying to make the logo bigger without increasing the header size, trying to make all more slim but without success.

Any tips for both problems?

[image: The social is in the same block as the logo]

```css
body {
  background-color: #45a29e;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.head {
  background-color: #137B77;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 15%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-menus {}

.header-menus ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}

.header-menus ul li a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 2.0;
  font-family: 'STIX Two Math', serif;
}

.logo-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.social {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.social-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="head">
    <div class="header-menus">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="">Home</a>
          <a href="">Contato</a>
          <a href="">Portfólio</a>
          <a href="">Localização</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main-header">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Makeup" class="center">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="social-menu">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photos/facebook.png">
      <a href="photos/facebook.png" class="fa fa-facebook">f</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what problem you're trying to solve. Have you looked at the flexbox layout options? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your logo without seeing the dimensions of the actual image. I have substituted my own image address for the sake of this question. Some of your code is not necessary such as the .center class. most of what you want to accomplish can be achieved by using some justify-content styling and manually adjusting the position of the logo. Also, you are targeting the logo-image div for the size but if you adjust the actual  tag then you can change the size without too much issues. If the logo image is square then you will have some issues with sizing but you could use a negative top and bottom margin on the .image-logo class to remove the extra space.

```
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #45a29e;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .head {
    background-color: #137B77;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 25px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .main-header {
    display: flex;
    position: relative
  }

  .header-menus {
  }

  .header-menus ul {
    list-style: none;
    color: #000000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  .header-menus li {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }

  .header-menus li:first-child {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .logo-image img {
    max-width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    right: 75px
  }


  .header-menus ul li a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 2.0;
    font-family: 'STIX Two Math', serif;
  }

.social {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .social-menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

</style>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
  <header class="head">
    <div class="header-menus">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a href="">Contato</a>
            </li>
            <li>
          <a href="">Portfólio</a>
              </li>
              <li>
          <a href="">Localização</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main-header">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <img src="https://www.simpleskincare.com/sk-eu/content/dam/brands/simple/global_use/1620325-new-logo-simple.png.rendition.680.680.png" alt="Makeup" class="center">
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="social-menu">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photos/facebook.png">
      <a href="photos/facebook.png" class="fa fa-facebook">f</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
  </body>
```

[An image of the resulting render with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cquj0.png)

Comment: without the center class the logo and the other divs just get loose in the page, any tips for fixing this without making  unecessary coding ?

Comment: not if you are using justify-content, center. It accomplishes the same thing, but after checking out Alvie's answer, i agree mostly with him except for a couple things. check out my forked fiddle to see the result. https://jsfiddle.net/pepebusse/j4yp5nwz/37/

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome class fix (the first class is usually not fa. fab is used for brands, fas for solid icons etc)
`fa fa-facebook` -> `fab fa-facebook`

added `flex: 1` to nav menu & social menu
added `flex: 3` to main header

When used with positive numbers, flex can split sections proportionally:
// 20% navigation 60% main 20% social

.head align-items: stretch rather than center (expands to fill height, rather than just staying same and being centered) [could also use align-self on .main-header]

// .main-header align-items: stretch so .logo-image expands

.logo-image - display:flex; in order to center the img

```css
.logo-image{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Center logo image, width/height: auto (keeps aspect ratio and expands), padding: 1em so there is some space around it

```css
.logo-image img {
    padding: 1em;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #45a29e;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.head{
    background-color: #137B77;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
}
.center{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 15%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.main-header{
    flex: 3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.header-menus{
    flex: 1;
}
.header-menus ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #000000;
}
.header-menus ul li a{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 2.0;
    font-family: 'STIX Two Math', serif;
}
.logo-image{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.logo-image img {
    padding: 1em;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.social{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.social-menu{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Heloisa Antoniely │ Makeup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Makeup.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Thiago Marvin">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=STIX+Two+Math&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="head">
            <div class="header-menus">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Home</a>
                        <a href="">Contato</a>
                        <a href="">Portfólio</a>
                        <a href="">Localização</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
            <div class="main-header">
                <div class="logo-image">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/400/100" alt="Makeup" class="center">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="social-menu">
                <a class="fab fa-facebook"></a>
                <a class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```